# Perl - DBI cannot connect to MySQL (Access Denied...)

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I've the following Perl Script through which I try to connect to my local MySQL Server,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;

my $driver = "mysql"; 
my $host = "localhost";
my $database = "test";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database,host=$host";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "password";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select from_date,to_date from temp");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
print "Number of rows found :" + $sth->rows;
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   my ($from_date, $to_date ) = @row;
   print "From Date = $from_date, To Date = $to_date\n";
}
$sth->finish();
```

When I run this script, I get the below error every time though I gave all privileges to this MySQL user,

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm new to Perl, I guess some mistake have been done. Please tell me what's wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance!!

**P.S. I'm running this on a Windows machine and I get the same error even on my Ubuntu machine though I specify socket's path there.**

Comment: Looks like you password is wrong. The code looks ok.

Comment: No.. The password is correct...

Comment: Can you login from console? with same use/password?

Comment: Can you try: `$connect = Mysql->connect($host, $database, $userid, $password);` ?

Comment: try: `$dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";`

Comment: @Jens Tried this, still same error... :(

Comment: You are using two machines (Windows and Ubuntu) and always connecting to "localhost": are you sure? Where is the database? Are you connecting from the same machine?

Comment: @Matteo I've two different servers on both the machines... I've tried the code individually on both of them.

Comment: Do you connect with this command: `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`?

Comment: Change `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;` to `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, {RaiseError=>1} ) or die $DBI::errstr;` and see whether you get any verbose error message

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Tried... yet the same error... :-(

Comment: I would get on the ubuntu box, and run your prel program under strace, capture the output, and then look for the login attempt and see what's going on at the system call level. It might shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issue.
I was using below connection string;

`my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=db_name;host=db_server_ip", "db_user", "db_password", {'RaiseError' => 1});`

password was having "@" symbol within, replacing double quotes (") to single quotes (') solved for me.

`my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=db_name;host=db_server_ip", "db_user", 'db_password', {'RaiseError' => 1});`

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql the username includes the host of connection.

For instance the same user can have two different passwords depending from where they connect.

Example:

root@localhost is a different user than root@192.168.1.1

Try and reset your password?
In the mysql console run both of the following command.
(Changing 'cleartext password' to your password)

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');

This will allow both root users to use the same password

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your password from double quotes to single quotes.

In your case, change your password from

```
my $password = "password";
```

to

```
my $password = 'password';
```